# Getting tableView without its empty cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, tableview

I need to get tableView like VC.view

I create TVC in nib. And instantiate it with

```
CustomTableViewController *customTableViewController = [[CustomTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CustomTableViewController" bundle:nil];
```

Then I want to add it to my custom alert with code

```
 alertView.contentView = customTableViewController.view;
```

And it works. But....

Difficulties is here.

I have 5 rows in table view with different cell height.
And then I add it to other view I have all height of VC.

How can I get tableView without its empty cells or its background?
Setting BG color to clear does not helps

I know problem is here because then I create VC with nib, tableView did not setted, but then I already add it to the view - its sets with all its height

Comment: Why not make the height of the tableview be the same as the total height of the rows (or smaller)?

Comment: rmaddy, how (using numberOfRowInSection?) and where(2 times because I need height before TV sets and after:1.initWithNibName, 2.viewDidLoad ) -- am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set an empty view to tabview footer view. It will hide the empty Cells.

```
self.tableView.tableFooterView = [UIView new];
```